# Showing sharepoint group Logo in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

```
         I have mentioned group logo in sharepoint 2010. So when i log in with user credentials, the group logo of users should be displayed at top right of sharepoint site.
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: How do you plan on managing the associated logo for the group?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. Just edit the page and add a web-part to display the logo.

Comment: You need to be a site collection admin to modify a web page. If you are, click on Site Settings -> Edit this page and create a web part.

Comment: I tried but it ask me to add webpart not to create webpart. Are you talking about using sharepoint designer?

Comment: My mistake. It should be add a webpart. Click on Edit Page -> Add A WebPart and add a "Image Web Part".

Comment: means image viewer webpart. i used this but not worked for me. i need sharepoint group logo of respected user who logged in has to be there on right top of the site.